# Android app for all devices

Tags: android, android-animation, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm working on an app that is targeted for version 2.3 so that it will run on my sister's phone. However, I can run 4.0 on my phone. I want to add some swipe animations and such but I don't run the animations to run on her phone.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Anything's possible with Android!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply put the API specific code in a if/else block, so it is only called when the system supports it:

Like this:

```
if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
//do things that are only supported on JellyBean
} else {
//do the other stuff
}
```

Comment: It's more complicated than that. If you, for example, try to create an instance of a JellyBean-only class within that if(), the enclosing activity class won't load on Android < 4, citing a reference to a nonexistent class. So test on both, and use reflection when necessary.

Comment: Not true. If you are building your app with the JB version of Android targeted it will find the reference.  I think reflection is over-complicated.

Comment: How about you try it yourself? It's not about the build target, it's about what's available at run time.

Comment: I run this code today in production (to take advantage of JB notifications when I can).

Comment: I know this is additional to the question but will I be able to take advantage of Jelly Bean functionality (such as animation libraries) even though I'm compiling for 2.3?

Comment: No you will not, you can only control when they are used.  Some backwards compatibility is supported via the Android Support Library.  Otherwise, there is an open-source product named "Nine Old Androids" that allows you to use animations on all versions of Android (written by Jake Wharton, the author of ActionBarSherlock - so it is a solid library).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` to provide swipe functionality among various `Fragment`s. All of which are available in the support library.

`ViewPager`(Note, don't do anything with the `ActionBar`, as they are not yet in the support library):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

`FragmentPagerAdapter`(pretty much the example code you will need):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

`Fragment`:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html